# docker container mariadb volumes

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb

I have a MariaDB container, to handle my database.

Here is my problem, I execute :

```
docker-compose exec mariadb mysql -u root
```

to enter MariaDB container and create a test database, then exit the container, and shut it down through command :

```
docker-compose down
```

After that, I start back all my containers through command

```
docker-compose up
```

go back inside the MariaDB container to see if the database I added persisted but, I found out it did not. I thought I had correctly parameterized MariaDB volumes through this line in my docker-compose :

```
- '/bitnami/mariadb/:/var/lib/mysql'
```

Here is my complete docker-compose.yml file :

```
version: '2'
services:
 myapp:
  image: 'bitnami/symfony:1'
  ports:
    - '8000:8000'
  volumes:
    - '.:/app'
  environment:
    - SYMFONY_PROJECT_NAME=backend
    - MARIADB_HOST=mariadb
    - MARIADB_PORT_NUMBER=3306
    - MARIADB_USER=monty
    - MARIADB_PASSWORD=monty
    - MARIADB_DATABASE=test
  container_name: symfony_container
  depends_on:
    - mariadb
mariadb:
  image: 'bitnami/mariadb:10.3'
  ports:
    - '3306:3306'
  volumes:
    - '/bitnami/mariadb/:/var/lib/mysql'
  environment:
    - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    - MARIADB_DATABASE=test
    - MARIADB_PORT_NUMBER=3306
    - MARIADB_ROOT_USER=root
    - MARIADB_USER=monty
    - MARIADB_PASSWORD=monty
  container_name: mariadb
```

If anyone have any leads for me I'll be greatfull.

Comment: You are starting the container using docker and stopping with docker composer? Makes no sense. You are starting a contaner that has no relation with your docker-compose file, so it will not have a volume attached

Comment: ok, what should I do instead ?

Comment: `docker-compose up`, then `docker-compose exec mariadb bash`

Comment: Ok, I see what you meant, thanks for your comment! Still, it did not fix my problems with data persistence.

Comment: I'm not sure what image bitnami uses, but the [official mariadb image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb) will automatically create the `MYSQL_DATABASE` if it doesn't exist. If that bitnami image doesn't allow for similar behavior, either `exec` to the already running container as mentioned, or run a script on container start that checks the status and creates and/or populates the db as required.

Answer (score 5):

Update, since this was asked, docker has changed the paths for the volume mounts. See the current documentation at https://github.com/docker-library/docs/blob/master/mariadb/README.md#where-to-store-data

Use the following to mount `/path/on/host` from the host to `/var/lib/mysql` in the container:

```yaml
  - '/path/on/host:/var/lib/mysql'
```

Comment: https://github.com/gct-faisal/bitnami-docker-mariadb#persisting-your-database
here's an updated link

Comment: @Motonari that's a very stale personal clone of the docker repo. I've updated with the new link.